# Output encoding (show characters after encoding in jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

In my jsp form, when I enter these special characters,
`!"#$%&*+/:;=?@[]^{|}~\`

what it shows on the screen is same as above but instead of " and & it shows the html entities as `&quot;` and `&amp;` which is good for those two characters. But I want to display all other special characters as below

`&#033;&amp;amp&#059;QUOT&#059;&#035;&#036;&#037;&amp;amp&#059;AMP&#059;&#042;&#043;&#047;`

Behind the screens it is encoding all the characters but when I display on the screen, only two are encoded, all others are decoded again and shown on the screen!

How can I change that to show only encoded values without decoding?

for every request, I convert the form field values using a EscapeCharactersUtility class something like

```
     while (character != CharacterIterator.DONE ){
       if (character == '<') {
         result.append("&lt;");
       }
       else if (character == '>') {
         result.append("&gt;");
       }
       else if (character == '&') {
         result.append("&amp;");
      }
       else if (character == '\"') {
         result.append("&quot;");
       }
       else if (character == '\t') {
         addCharEntity(9, result);
       }
       else if (character == '!') {
         addCharEntity(33, result);
       }
}
```

addCharEntity is used to append `&#`and `;`

I do the conversion in processFormFieldValue method in following class,

```
public class CSRFRequestDataValueProcessor implements RequestDataValueProcessor {


@Override
public String processAction(HttpServletRequest request, String action) {
    return action;
}

@Override
public String processFormFieldValue(HttpServletRequest request, String name, String value, String type) {
    value = EscapeCharactersUtility.forHTML(value);
    return value;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getExtraHiddenFields(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String> hiddenFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hiddenFields.put(CSRFTokenManager.CSRF_TOKEN_NAME, CSRFTokenManager.getTokenForSession(request.getSession()));
    return hiddenFields;
}

@Override
public String processUrl(HttpServletRequest request, String url) {
    return url;
}
```

}

Comment: what did you do? show some your jsp code.

Comment: its not pertaining to one jsp page, basically I want to change the request and reponse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you encode the characters, the browser will decode them and show the character on the screen.  That's normal.  If you want to literally show the codes rather than the characters in the browser, you need to do it like this

```
&lt; becomes &amp;lt;
&quot; becomes &amp;quot;
```

The result of that will be that on screen rather than seeing the less than symbol and quote you will literally see

```
&lt;
&quot;
```

So

```
   if (character == '<') {
     result.append("&amp;lt;");
   }
  else if (character == '&') {
     result.append("&amp;amp;");
  }
```